# Efficient custom ordering in Julia DataFrames?

Tags: dataframe, julia

Is there a quick method for specifying a custom order to `sort`/`sort!` on Julia DataFrames?

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> srand(1);

julia> df = DataFrame(x = rand(10), y = rand([:high, :med, :low], 10))
10×2 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ x          │ y    │
├─────┼────────────┼──────┤
│ 1   │ 0.236033   │ med  │
│ 2   │ 0.346517   │ high │
│ 3   │ 0.312707   │ high │
│ 4   │ 0.00790928 │ med  │
│ 5   │ 0.488613   │ med  │
│ 6   │ 0.210968   │ med  │
│ 7   │ 0.951916   │ low  │
│ 8   │ 0.999905   │ low  │
│ 9   │ 0.251662   │ high │
│ 10  │ 0.986666   │ med  │

julia> sort!(df, cols=[:y])
10×2 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ x          │ y    │
├─────┼────────────┼──────┤
│ 1   │ 0.346517   │ high │
│ 2   │ 0.312707   │ high │
│ 3   │ 0.251662   │ high │
│ 4   │ 0.951916   │ low  │
│ 5   │ 0.999905   │ low  │
│ 6   │ 0.236033   │ med  │
│ 7   │ 0.00790928 │ med  │
│ 8   │ 0.488613   │ med  │
│ 9   │ 0.210968   │ med  │
│ 10  │ 0.986666   │ med  │
```

I would like to have the `y` column ordered with `:low` first, followed by `:med` and `:high`. What would be the best way of doing this? I know I can do the following:

```
julia> subdfs = []
0-element Array{Any,1}

julia> for val in [:low, :med, :high]
           push!(subdfs, df[df[:y] .== val, :])
       end

julia> vcat(subdfs...)
10×2 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ x          │ y    │
├─────┼────────────┼──────┤
│ 1   │ 0.951916   │ low  │
│ 2   │ 0.999905   │ low  │
│ 3   │ 0.236033   │ med  │
│ 4   │ 0.00790928 │ med  │
│ 5   │ 0.488613   │ med  │
│ 6   │ 0.210968   │ med  │
│ 7   │ 0.986666   │ med  │
│ 8   │ 0.346517   │ high │
│ 9   │ 0.312707   │ high │
│ 10  │ 0.251662   │ high │
```

Is there a way to do this without allocating memory since in my actual example, `df` is quite large?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a comparison function:

```
lmhlt(x, y) = x == :low && y != :low || x == :med && y == :high
```

Then use

```
sort!(df, lt=lmhlt)
```

However, this still allocates memory. It should be less than your current version though.

Comment: Nice!  Thanks!  I had to search in the [docs](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/sort/) to fully understand the `lt` argument here.  They said: "All the sorting and order related functions rely on a “less than” relation defining a total order on the values to be manipulated. The `isless` function is invoked by default, but the relation can be specified via the `lt` keyword."

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [a function to generalize custom sorting](https://github.com/sylvaticus/LAJuliaUtils.jl/blob/master/src/LAJuliaUtils.jl) to multiple column just specifying for each column that require sorting the custom order:

```
Pkg.clone("https://github.com/sylvaticus/LAJuliaUtils.jl.git")
using DataFrames, LAJuliaUtils
df = DataFrame(
  c1 = ['a','b','c','a','b','c'],
  c2 = ["aa","aa","bb","bb","cc","cc"],
  c3 = [1,2,3,10,20,30],
)
customSort!(df, [(:c2,["bb","cc"]),(:c1,['b','a','c'])])

6×3 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ c1  │ c2   │ c3 │
├─────┼─────┼──────┼────┤
│ 1   │ 'a' │ "bb" │ 10 │
│ 2   │ 'c' │ "bb" │ 3  │
│ 3   │ 'b' │ "cc" │ 20 │
│ 4   │ 'c' │ "cc" │ 30 │
│ 5   │ 'b' │ "aa" │ 2  │
│ 6   │ 'a' │ "aa" │ 1  │
```

You can get more details once installed the package using `?customSort!`

The function uses internally the `sort!()` DataFrames function with the `by` keyword over an `OrderedDict` built based on the user-provided custom order, as suggested by the user Tamas_Papp on [Julia Discourse](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/custom-dataframe-column-sort-order/3716/3).