# Custom sort for SubDataFrame

Tags: sorting, dataframe, julia

I'm trying to apply a custom sorting algorithm to a bunch of subdataframes in order to make some plots. With the help of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37932963/efficient-custom-ordering-in-julia-dataframes), I'm able to sort my dataframe with a custom order:

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> df = DataFrame(x = rand(10), y = rand([:low, :med, :high], 10), z = rand([:a, :b], 10))
10×3 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ x         │ y    │ z │
├─────┼───────────┼──────┼───┤
│ 1   │ 0.436891  │ low  │ b │
│ 2   │ 0.370725  │ high │ b │
│ 3   │ 0.521269  │ low  │ b │
│ 4   │ 0.071102  │ high │ a │
│ 5   │ 0.969407  │ high │ a │
│ 6   │ 0.0416023 │ med  │ b │
│ 7   │ 0.63486   │ med  │ b │
│ 8   │ 0.4352    │ high │ b │
│ 9   │ 0.626739  │ low  │ b │
│ 10  │ 0.151149  │ low  │ a │

julia> o = [:low, :med, :high]
3-element Array{Symbol,1}:
 :low 
 :med 
 :high

julia> custom_sort(x,y) = findfirst(o, x) < findfirst(o, y)
custom_sort (generic function with 1 method)

julia> sort!(df, cols=[:y], lt=custom_sort)
10×3 DataFrames.DataFrame
│ Row │ x         │ y    │ z │
├─────┼───────────┼──────┼───┤
│ 1   │ 0.436891  │ low  │ b │
│ 2   │ 0.521269  │ low  │ b │
│ 3   │ 0.626739  │ low  │ b │
│ 4   │ 0.151149  │ low  │ a │
│ 5   │ 0.0416023 │ med  │ b │
│ 6   │ 0.63486   │ med  │ b │
│ 7   │ 0.370725  │ high │ b │
│ 8   │ 0.071102  │ high │ a │
│ 9   │ 0.969407  │ high │ a │
│ 10  │ 0.4352    │ high │ b │
```

and it works great. The trouble is, when I then do a `groupby()`, the custom sorting gets lost:

```
julia> groupby(df, [:y, :z])
DataFrames.GroupedDataFrame  5 groups with keys: Symbol[:y, :z]
First Group:
2×3 DataFrames.SubDataFrame{Array{Int64,1}}
│ Row │ x        │ y    │ z │
├─────┼──────────┼──────┼───┤
│ 1   │ 0.071102 │ high │ a │
│ 2   │ 0.969407 │ high │ a │
⋮
Last Group:
2×3 DataFrames.SubDataFrame{Array{Int64,1}}
│ Row │ x         │ y   │ z │
├─────┼───────────┼─────┼───┤
│ 1   │ 0.0416023 │ med │ b │
│ 2   │ 0.63486   │ med │ b │
```

Is there a way I can sort the `SubDataFrame`s so that eg. the first group is has `y == :low` and `z == a`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`groupby` takes advantage of the PooledArray machinery to split the DataFrame in to groups. When creating a PooledArray out of a vector the order is not kept... unless specified in the PooledArray constructor. It is possible to trick `groupby` by making the columns already into PooledArrays with a desired order. In code:

```
julia> df[:y] = PooledDataArray(df[:y],[:low,:med,:high])

julia> df[:z] = PooledDataArray(df[:z],[:a,:b])

julia> groupby(df, [:y, :z])
DataFrames.GroupedDataFrame  6 groups with keys: Symbol[:y, :z]
First Group:
1×3 DataFrames.SubDataFrame{Array{Int64,1}}
│ Row │ x        │ y   │ z │
├─────┼──────────┼─────┼───┤
│ 1   │ 0.833255 │ low │ a │
⋮
Last Group:
1×3 DataFrames.SubDataFrame{Array{Int64,1}}
│ Row │ x        │ y    │ z │
├─────┼──────────┼──────┼───┤
│ 1   │ 0.604117 │ high │ b │
```

This can also be automated for more columns or columns with more values with the following loop:

```
for v in [:y,:z]
    df[v] = PooledDataArray(df[v],unique(Vector(df[v])))
end
```

which does the same as the explicit assignments earlier.

Comment: Presumably I need to do the custom sort on any columns requiring it prior to making the `PooledDataArray` with your loop?

Comment: @kevbonham Yes. In fact, it seems one should be able to sort the columns according to the order desired in `groupby` , and pool the columns. Afterwards sort the dataframe with a different order altogether and do the `groupby`.